What's Wrong with the color ramp?
The threshold is so low, and I can't really set anything besides these two states on the picture.
I'm trying to do a procedural material mouth rig, and now I'm at making the teeth.
The object is just a plane with 4 faces that I inset two times, and then I put a subdivision modifier on it without applying it to the object. I did everything exactly as I saw in the tutorial, so I have no idea what's wrong.
Mouth:

Mouth with teeth:


May I see the tutorial you used for reference?

Best advice I can give: Open a new file and start whatever tutorial you are watching over. This is how they are meant to be followed - if something goes wrong, do it again until you get it. If the tutorial is for the version of Blender you have and you are following it with factory settings loaded(File->Defaults-> Load Factory Settings) or settings the tutor tells you about, if you have a problem always assume you did something wrong, because that is what happens with beginners and tutorials in pretty much all cases. Don't worry - it's not a waste of time, you are learning.

Without knowing what this is supposed to do nor what it is supposed to look like vs what you have, we can't really help much. Please [edit] your question to show what you are aiming for, your tutorial source, maybe even share your file. You use the Object's texture coordinate, so anything you get from that depends on your object, including its origin position, orientation, scale and dimensions.

I managed to do it just a second ago!
I guess in the latest version putting the separate xyzzy vector to the object node of the texture coordinate doesn't work, but the generated does
